# Angular on refresh getItem undefined for Local storage service

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I am trying to save a value in localStorage and to retrieve it on refresh.
I have created a local-storage service and I set a local storage value by calling the service.

on refresh I want to retrieve the value so I have the following in my appComponent ngOnInit..

```
ngOnInit() {
// Service which returns undefined
console.log(this.ls.getLocalStorage('test'))

// local which returns value...
console.log(localStorage.getItem('test'));
```

}

and in my local-storage-service I have the following.

```
getLocalStorage(k) {
    console.log(k);
    localStorage.getItem(k);
}
```

the first one in my onInit returns undefined, yet the second one returns the correct value.

Why is this happening and is there a way to resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning any value within your function. Please add the `return` keyword.

```
getLocalStorage(k) {
    console.log(k);
    return localStorage.getItem(k);
}
```

Comment: Spot on. I copied the getItem from my appComponent and completely forgot about the return. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a `return` statement

Your method has to look like this:

```
getLocalStorage(k) {
    return localStorage.getItem(k);
}
```